# Starting multiple private network in one computer causes Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: Access is denied

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

Question: How to fix `Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: Access is denied`?

 
Here is the steps that I try:

1. `geth --datadir block1 init /d/nodes/_ethereum/genesis.json`
2. `geth --datadir block1 --networkid 1234 --rpc --rpcport 1201 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" console 2>console.log`
3. First node running successfully...
4. `geth --datadir block2 init /d/nodes/_ethereum/genesis.json`
5. I created my new block...
6. `geth --datadir block2 --port 30304 --networkid 1234 --rpcport 1201 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --nodiscover console 2>console.log`

I also tried using: `--rpcaddr [my current ip address]`

This happens when I run the second node:
`Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: Access is denied`

Windows 10 Home 64bit

Comment: make sure about the permission on the folder `block2`

Comment: @HaĐANG `chmod 777 -R [folder path]` yes thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command `--ipcdisable` as shown on this issue [#1714](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/1714) to make it run.